# Wordpress network .htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress network setup but currently there is only one subsite with the url

/psychology

In the future there will be addition sites with

/md
/vet

but for the time being there will only be /psychology

What I want to do is have a rewrite rule in my htaccess that when a user visits the root of the site (/) it actually loads the /psychology site.

I tried adding a line like this to my htaccess

RewriteRule (.*) psychology/$1 [R,L]

but it broke the site. here is my current htaccess (basically the wordpress default for a network install)

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ASKanALLY/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 # uploaded files
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

 # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
 RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the base to the RewriteRule destination. And add a condition so you don't get a redirect loop.

Adding these two lines after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ASKanALLY/psychology  ## Not already viewing a psychology URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ASKanALLY/psychology/$1 [R,L]  ## Redirect to psychology
```

Here's the complete example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ASKanALLY/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ASKanALLY/psychology  ## Not already viewing a psychology URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ASKanALLY/psychology/$1 [R,L]  ## Redirect to psychology

RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is so close! The redirect works but none of my style sheets or images are working. When I paste the urls for them into my webbrowser it says its in a redirect loop.

http://localhost/ASKanALLY/psychology/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/headers/shore.jpg

Comment: The new directives should be placed after checking for existence of file / directory (`-f` and `-d` flags). I've updated the answer with the complete example.

Comment: Nathan this is really close i get a 500 error when I try to use your .htaccess code.

Comment: I got it to work using
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ASKanALLY/psychology
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.png$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ASKanALLY/psychology/$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` didn't work because it was matching all URLs, including ones to `/psychology/foo`. I'm guessing you don't have a `.htaccess` file under /psychology?

Try this - it'll rewrite just the root.

`RewriteRule ^/$ psychology/ [r=301,L]`

Comment: I am running this on localhost so the root of my blog is
    http://localhost/ASKanALLY/

I tried putting that rule on the top of my htaccess right after  RewriteBase /ASKanALLY/ and it didn't do anything...